# RecyclerView is Not Displaying Adapter's Data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

My `RecyclerView` is displaying empty `CardView`. I don't see where I went wrong. Android Studio doesn't fail at compile tile and the app doesn't fail during run time either. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my data class

```
data class Notes(
    var title: String,
    var description: String
)
```

This is my adapter

```
class MyNotesAdapter(private val notesList: MutableList<Notes>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyNotesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var textViewTitle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle)
        var textViewDescr: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescr)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_notes_adapter_layout,
            parent, false) 
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textViewTitle.text = notesList[position].title
        holder.textViewDescr.text = notesList[position].description
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = notesList.size
}
```

This is my adapter layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TITLE HERE"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="DESCR HERE"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textViewTitle" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

That is how I setup my RecyclerView in my main activity

```
private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    val myNotesAdapter: MyNotesAdapter = MyNotesAdapter(notesList)
    val linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    linearLayoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.VERTICAL

    recyclerViewNotes = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNotes)
    recyclerViewNotes.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    recyclerViewNotes.adapter = myNotesAdapter
}
```

My `RecyclerView` function gets called here

```
private fun setupDialogBox() {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.add_notes_dialog_layout, null)
        var dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(view)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
        dialog.show()

        buttonSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit)
        editTextTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle)
        editTextDescr = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDescr)

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener {
            notes = Notes(editTextTitle.text.toString(), editTextDescr.text.toString())
            notesList.add(notes)
            setupRecyclerView()
            dialog.hide()
        }
    }
```

My dialog gets called within main activity `onCreate()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_notes)
    ......

    fabButton.setOnClickListener {
        setupDialogBox()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe its the `match_parent` on your `ConstraintLayout`. Its parent is set to `wrap_content` so there is a conflict there. Try `wrap_content` on the `ConstraintLayout`'s height.

Comment: If what @StuStirling said is true (might be, I had this issue at times), you should still be able to scroll the items, they just take up the whole screen.

Comment: Check the size of `noteList`, it should be empty. That is why it is showing the list items

Comment: The Fragment or Activity that is hosting the dialog should have called `setupRecyclerView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="TITLE HERE"
>     ....
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
> ```

The problem is in the `ConstraintLayout` as the `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"` of the top `TextView` is set to the bottom of the `ConstraintLayout`.

This includes that the height of the `ConstraintsLayout` is calculated from `match_parent` i.e. it equals to the parent (so, it takes the full height of the item layout), and therefore the `TextViews` won't be shown on the List item or on the screen.

Also as the CardView height is `wrap_content`, then the `ConstraintLayout` will tend to take the minimum possible height to that ViewGroup.

To fix this you need to replace this constraint of the `textViewTitle`:

```
`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"`
```

With:

```
`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the size of `noteList`, it should be empty. That is why it is showing the list-items
2. The Fragment or Activity that is hosting the dialog should have called `setupRecyclerView()`
3. You repeatedly called `setupRecyclerView()` in  `setupDialogBox()`
4. If none of this works, then give CardView a height, don't use `wrap_content`, I use `wrap_content` only when I am using LinearLayout

Comment: Why should my adapter be empty. I have to pass notesList filled with data so adapter feeds into recycler view this is how I did it val myNotesAdapter: MyNotesAdapter = MyNotesAdapter(notesList)..... I will try you suggestions later. I hope it works